# sql sp_sqlexec dealing with single quotes in statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm using `sp_sqlexec` and was wondering how you deal with single quotes within the statement string **'problem'**

```
declare @id int =1
declare @sql nvarchar(200)

set @sql = '
insert into mytable (col1,col2) values (1, 'problem')
'
exec sp_sqlexec @sql
```

Comment: I strongly recommend you use sp_executesql instead of sp_sqlexec, which is undocumented and unsupported in current SQL versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better than handling those extra quotes you could change your dynamic sql to use parameters. (Note this is using sp_executesql instead of sp_sqlexec because it allows for parameters)

```
declare @id int = 1
declare @sql nvarchar(2000)

declare @col2 varchar(10) = 'problem'

set @sql = 'insert into mytable (col1, col2) values (1, @col2)'

exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@Col2 varchar(10)', @col2 = @col2
```

Answer (score 3):

You can escape them with single quotes `'`:

```
 set @sql = '
 insert into mytable (col1,col2) values (1, ''problem'')'
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/759a9c/1)

Answer (score 2):

Double single quotes escapes to a single quote:

```
set @sql = 'insert into mytable (col1,col2) values (1, ''problem'')'
```